# Selenium get_attribute("id")

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

I am scraping in Python using Selenium and Firefox.

I am able to get my href's into an object using the following:

```python
HREF = node.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a") # Get the href's under the current node
```

Which returns a bunch of `<a>` tags that look like this:

```html
<a href="http://example.com" class="" title="The Link" data-ipshover="" data-ipshover-target="http://example.com/?preview=1" data-ipshover-timeout="1.5" id="ips_uid_1234_9">
    <span>The Link</span>
</a>
```

There are multiple links returned, but if I just focus on the first one:

```python
print dir(HREF[0])
print "#########"
print HREF[0].text
print HREF[0].id
print HREF[0].get_attribute("title")
print HREF[0].get_attribute("href")
print HREF[0].get_attribute("data-ipshover-timeout")
print HREF[0].get_attribute("id")
print "#########"
```

Outputs this:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
'__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__',
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
'__weakref__', '_execute', '_id', '_parent', '_upload', '_w3c',
'anonymous_children', 'clear', 'click',
'find_anonymous_element_by_attribute', 'find_element',
'find_element_by_class_name', 'find_element_by_css_selector',
'find_element_by_id', 'find_element_by_link_text',
'find_element_by_name', 'find_element_by_partial_link_text',
'find_element_by_tag_name', 'find_element_by_xpath', 'find_elements',
'find_elements_by_class_name', 'find_elements_by_css_selector',
'find_elements_by_id', 'find_elements_by_link_text',
'find_elements_by_name', 'find_elements_by_partial_link_text',
'find_elements_by_tag_name', 'find_elements_by_xpath', 'get_attribute',
'get_property', 'id', 'is_displayed', 'is_enabled', 'is_selected',
'location', 'location_once_scrolled_into_view', 'parent', 'rect',
'screenshot', 'screenshot_as_base64', 'screenshot_as_png', 'send_keys',
'size', 'submit', 'tag_name', 'text', 'value_of_css_property']
#########
The Link
101b851e-67dd-4907-a2da-2dc1828cb09c
The Link
http://example.com
1.5

#########
```

Note that last attribute print is blank, when is should return `ips_uid_1234_9`.  Every other attribute returns fine, so I'm not sure why "id" won't return correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the first hyperlink has id ?

Comment: Positive.  The link text and hyper link match the HTML I am looking at.  Also, if you select a non-existent attribute with get_attribute, it returns "None", it doesn't return a blank unicode string.

Comment: I tried with duplicate ids, and different ids. It worked correctly in both the cases. Which website you're scraping ? The website might be changing ids during the run using JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out.  I'm scraping with firefox but have been looking at the page source in Chrome.  Apparently the "id" attribute doesn't exist if you look at the site in Firefox.  Odd, but that at least explains my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a knucklehead. Next time I need to use the same browser for scraping and viewing source code...  Attribute doesn't load in Firefox, but it does load in Chrome.